# Scale_size_area and scale_radius

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good day,

Does anyone understand how R handles scale functions? That's not a circle drawn on a 1:1 scale.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, size = hwy))+geom_point(data=, aes(x=1,y=1), colour="Red", shape=1)+scale_size_area(pi)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, size = hwy))+geom_point(data=, aes(x=1,y=1), colour="Red", shape=1)+scale_radius(1)
```

[image: Drawn using scale_size_area]
[image: Drawn using scale_radius]

R console tells me that:

```
> scale_size_area()
<ScaleContinuous>
 Range:  
 Limits:    0 --    1
> scale_radius()
<ScaleContinuous>
 Range:  
 Limits:    0 --    1
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you know how to draw a circle in geom_point of radius=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to draw geom_point objects with any size you like using scale_radius:

```
library("ggplot2")
jpeg(filename="circulo.jpeg",width=400 , height=400)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, size = hwy))+geom_point(data=, aes(x=1,y=1), colour="Red", shape=1)+scale_radius(labels=NULL, trans="identity", range=c(165,165), guide=FALSE)
dev.off()
```

The size of the object varies with the width and height of the image, here's a circle of diameter=1 for a width of 400 and height of 400.

[image]

For some strange reason this doesn't work with scale_size_area().